# How can I extract the URL?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to scraping and parsing. I want to extract the URL. But I am getting

none
none

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "xabh.com"
r = requests.get('http://xabh.com')
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,'lxml')

soup.find_all('meta')

for link in soup.find_all('meta'):
    print(link.get('url'))
```

This is the **soup**

```
<html><head><title>XABH</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="0; url=http://www.xabh.com/scripts/detailsnew.asp?id=mar0617" http-equiv="refresh"/>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the `meta` element that contains `url` substring inside `content`. Then, you can split by the `;` and then by the `url=`:

```
In [8]: content = soup.select_one("meta[content*=url]")["content"]

In [9]: content.split(";")[-1].split("url=")[-1]
Out[9]: 'http://www.xabh.com/scripts/detailsnew.asp?id=mar0617'
```

Or, you can apply a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to the `content` attribute of the `meta` elements and then reuse the same expression to extract the url:

```
In [10]: import re

In [11]: pattern = re.compile(r"url=(.*?)$")

In [12]: content = soup.find("meta", content=pattern)["content"]

In [13]: pattern.search(content).group(1)
Out[13]: 'http://www.xabh.com/scripts/detailsnew.asp?id=mar0617'
```